# in_array giving Warning Message

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

All,
I have the following code:

```
$qry = "Select * from vendor_options order by vendor_option_name ASC";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
while($resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['pav_choosen_vendor_categories'])){
        for($z=0;$z<$_SESSION['pav_choosen_vendor_categories'];$z++){
            $sVendorId = $_SESSION['pav_vendor_categories_' . $z];
                if($sVendorId==$resultset['vendor_option_id']){
                    $vendor_cats_choosen[] = $sVendorId;
                }
        }
        if(in_array($resultset['vendor_option_id'],$vendor_cats_choosen)){
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_id']; ?>" class="select_vendor" name="vendor_categories[]" checked><?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_name']; ?><br>
            <?php
        }else{
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_id']; ?>" class="select_vendor" name="vendor_categories[]"><?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_name']; ?><br>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to check to see if the value returned in the mysql_fetch_array is already in my array. Say the first value it finds in the array is in the fourth iteration of the while loop. I'll get the following error:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
```

Once it gets to a value that is in the array the rest of them work fine. Why does itgive an error for the first couple? Thanks.

Comment: @NullUserException I can certainly add comments, how do you suppose that I would re-write this to make it better for the Data retrieval, business logic and presentation?

Comment: See: [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have not initialized `$vendor_cats_chosen` to be an array, and so if the condition `if($sVendorId==$resultset['vendor_option_id'])` is not true, no elements will be appended to it, turning it implicitly into an array.

Initialize it before the `while` loop.  You should just about always initialize arrays before use.

```
// Initialize the array
$vendor_cats_chosen = array();
while($resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  ....
```

Now, when your `in_array()` statement executes, the array may be empty, but will be a valid array.

```
// $vendor_cats_chosen might be an empty array, or may have elements.
if(in_array($resultset['vendor_option_id'],$vendor_cats_choosen)){
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your array not always creates. To fix this issue just add

```
$vendor_cats_choosen = array();
```

somewhere before `while` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever populate the array `$vendor_cats_choosen` inside an `if` statement, which means it can potentially contain no values. You also do not declare it before you start the loop which populates it - which you should do anyway, because adding a value to an undeclared array will emit an `E_NOTICE`.

Add the line

```
$vendor_cats_choosen = array();
```

...at the top of the script and the error will disappear. If you think this array should contain values, you may need to examine the logic in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In order to eliminate the warning message, two approaches can be followed:

1) use of `@` before the statement which is generating the warning message ( However, this is not an advisable engineering approach )

2) prior to using the `array` object, it can be filtered out in an `if-else`. 
For example, in your case, you can add this line

```
if( $vendor_cats_choosen ){

  if(in_array($resultset['vendor_option_id'],$vendor_cats_choosen)){
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_id']; ?>" class="select_vendor" name="vendor_categories[]" checked><?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_name']; ?><br>
        <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_id']; ?>" class="select_vendor" name="vendor_categories[]"><?php echo $resultset['vendor_option_name']; ?><br>
    <?php
    }

} ?>
```